# C# PDF work with tables

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a pdf file with some table inside.
I want to read this document and change some existing row and add new rows too.
Is there a way do do this?

Comment: "Adding content into the middle of a PDF page" is virtually impossible. Feasible manipulations of an existing PDF are restricted to painting over or under a page, and adding or removing whole pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't have any luck.

Unfortunately you don't get 'rows' in a PDF - there is no concept of a table in PDF - only text and vector graphics.

This means you will have to manually add the vectors and the text in the right places to give the illusion of a table.